# Determine if a PDF is using subsetted fonts

Tags: pdf, fonts

I'm creating PDFs with a library, and I know next to nothing about PDF.  I've been told by the people at the printers that they are having a problem with 'subsetted' fonts in the PDFs.  They want me to embed the entire font to see if this is causing the problem.

First step - I'd like to confirm the fonts are subsetted.  <strike>Acrobat Reader doesn't give me this info</strike> (correction: it's right there in the properties tab).  Is there some other utility (or library) that I could use to determine this.  I've had a quick look at the command line options for Ghostscript and can't find anything obvious.

I'm creating the pdfs in a C# app - but I'm happy to use any platform to diagnose this (Linux / C / Java / etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the free one sitting around anywhere, but the full version of Acrobat will certainly give that to you under File > Properties... > Fonts.

Yup, the free one does it, too.
[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20091221-83w6b5uhut9d4cdhekbphaja68.png](http://img.skitch.com/20091221-83w6b5uhut9d4cdhekbphaja68.png)